# mysql query with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-value

I have a database with a table for students. The structure is like this

```
id      name
---     -----
1       Tini
2       Eka
```

Then the table for books

```
id      title
---     ------
1       Cinderella's story
2       Pinochio
3       Mickey Mouse
```

Then for borrowing

```
id      students_id     books_id
---     ------------    ---------
1       1               1,3
2       2               2,3
```

How i get **"Tini is borrowing Cinderella's story and Mickey Mouse"** ?
I already tried query like this

```
select students.*, books.* , borrowing.*
    (select books.title from borrowing
     join books on books.id = borrowing.books_id
     where books_.id = borrowing.books_id limit 1)  as books_title
from borrowing
join students on students.id = borrowing.students_id
join books on books.id = borrowing.books_id 
GROUP BY books.title
```

But it throws me an error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing your query, it would be better to normalize data of the relation table `borrowing`.

Change to way of saving data like:

```
id      students_id     books_id
---     ------------    ---------
1       1               1
2       1               3
3       2               2
4       2               3
```

And the `id` column is not necessary too, you could omit it.

Then get the borrowing list for each students is quite simple:

```
SELECT t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.title) AS borrowed_books
FROM students t1
LEFT JOIN borrowing t2 ON t2.students_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN books t3 ON t3.id = t2.books_id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id      students_id     books_id
---     ------------    ---------
1       1               1
2       1               3
3       2               2
3       3               3

select s.name, bk.title
from student s
inner join borrowing b
on s.id = b.students_id
inner join book bk
on b.book_id = bk.id
where s.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, Create this function in you database.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[funcSplit]
(
    @param      NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE (val NVARCHAR(MAX))
--select * from dbo.funcSplit('1,3',',')
AS
BEGIN
    SET @param += @delimiter

    ;WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT CAST(1 AS BIGINT) f,
               CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param) t,
               1 seq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t + 1,
               CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param, t + 1),
               seq + 1
        FROM   a
        WHERE  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param, t + 1) > 0
    )
    INSERT @t
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@param, f, t - f)         
    FROM   a
           OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN
END
```

And then execute this code,

```
select s.sname,bk.bname,f.val from stud as s
left join  borrowing as b on s.sid = b.students_id
cross apply dbo.funcSplit(b.bookid,',') as f
left join books as bk on bk.bookid = f.val
where sid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to user group_concat() in query

provided you should have a table like @sotondolphin said in above answers to use the following query

try this

```
select user_id,group_concat(book_id) from userTable
inner join book_borrow_tbl on  userTable.user_id=book_borrow_tbl.user_id
group by user_id
```